# JavaScript Change the text fields when the user fills or not when the text field loses focus

Tags: javascript, css, dom

i need help with an assignment:
When a user fills in a text field and the text field loses focus, make the text field green with a check mark. You can use a check mark from FontAwesome.
When a user doesn't fill in a text field, but removes focus, make the text field red with a cross
I need the javascript/dom code to complete this assignment.
I have tried this code but doesnt work:

```
    let fields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
const checkFields = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].value == "") {
          fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else {
          fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
      }
}
fields.addEventListener('change', checkFields)



          <div class="controls">
            <input
              autofocus=""
              class="input-xlarge"
              id="company"
              name="company"
              placeholder="Company name"
              type="text"
              value=""
            />
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="fname">Name</label>

          <div class="controls two-col">
            <input
              class="input-medium"
              id="fname"
              name="fname"
              placeholder="First name"
              type="text"
              value=""
            />
          </div>

          <div class="controls two-col">
            <input
              class="input-medium"
              id="lname"
              name="lname"
              placeholder="Last name"
              type="text"
              value=""
            />
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>

          <div class="controls">
            <input
              class="input-xlarge"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              type="email"
              value=""
            />
          </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Please share the JS code that you have tried.

Comment: let fields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
const checkFields = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].value == "") {
          fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else {
          fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
      }
}
fields.addEventListener('change', checkFields)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```js
// Select Each Input
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((inp) => {
// Remove whitespace from value and check it
   // Add eventlistener on each input
  inp.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let value = inp.value.split(' ').join('')
  // Do something with value;
    if (value == "") {
      inp.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
      inp.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
  })
})
```

```html
        <section>
          <div class="controls">
            <input autofocus="" class="input-xlarge" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company name" type="text" value="" />
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="fname">Name</label>

          <div class="controls two-col">
            <input class="input-medium" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First name" type="text" value="" />
          </div>

          <div class="controls two-col">
            <input class="input-medium" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" type="text" value="" />
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>

          <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="" />
          </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: everythink is ok except that the input field should be red if its not entered any value once selected. with this code works only if has been typed smth then erased from the selected field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "focusout" event which I believe will be a better choice if I understood your problem right.

```
const ips = document.querySelectorAll("input")

ips.forEach(ip=>ip.addEventListener("focusout", ()=>{
    const text = ip.value
    if (text === "") ip.style.border= "1px solid red"
    else ip.style.border = "1px solid green"
 })
)
```